# React Hooks - Preventing child components from rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, rerender, react-memo

As a newbie in React, it seems that re-rendering of components is the thing not to do.
Therefore, for example, if I want to create a menu following this architecture :
`App` is parent of `Menu`, which have a `map` function which creates the `MenuItem` components

- menu items come from a data source (here it's `const data`)
- when I click on a `MenuItem`, it updates the state with the selected `MenuItem` value

for now it's fine, except that all the components are re-rendered (seen in the various `console.log`)

Here's the code :

App

```
import React, { useState} from "react"
import Menu from "./menu";

function App() {

  const data = ["MenuItem1", "MenuItem2", "MenuItem3", "MenuItem4", "MenuItem5", "MenuItem6"]

  const [selectedItem, setMenuItem] = useState(null)

  const handleMenuItem = (menuItem) => {
    setMenuItem(menuItem)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Menu items = {data} handleMenuItem = {handleMenuItem}></Menu>
      <div>{selectedItem}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Menu

```
import React from "react";
import MenuItem from "./menuItem";

const Menu = (props) => {

    return (
        <>
            {props.items.map((item, index) => {
                return <MenuItem key = {index} handleMenuItem = {props.handleMenuItem} value = {item}></MenuItem>
            })
            }
            {console.log("menuItem")}
        </>
    )
};

export default React.memo(Menu);
```

MenuItem

```
import React from "react";

const MenuItem = (props) => {

    return (
        <>
        <div onClick={() => props.handleMenuItem(props.value)}>
            <p>{props.value}</p>
        </div>
        {console.log("render du MenuItem")}
        </>
    )

};

export default React.memo(MenuItem);
```

as you might see, I've used the `React.memo` in the end of `MenuItem` but it does not work, as well as the `PureComponent`

If someone has an idea, that'd be great to have some advice.

Have a great day

Comment: Probably this article might help https://alexsidorenko.com/blog/react-list-rerender/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here so let's get started.

The way hooks are designed to prevent re-rendering components unnecessarily is by making sure you use the same instance of any unchanged variables, most specifically for object, functions, and arrays.  I say that because string, number, and boolean equality is simple  `'abc' === 'abc'` resolves to true, but `[] === []` would be false, as those are two DIFFERENT empty arrays being compared, and equality in JS for objects and functions and arrays only returns true when the two sides being compared are the exact same item.

That said, react provides ways to cache values and only update them (by creating new instances) when they need to be updated (because their dependencies change).  Let's start with your app.js

```js
import React, {useState, useCallback} from "react"
import Menu from "./menu";

// move this out of the function so that a new copy isn't created every time
// the App component re-renders

const data = ["MenuItem1", "MenuItem2", "MenuItem3", "MenuItem4", "MenuItem5", "MenuItem6"]

function App() {

  const [selectedItem, setMenuItem] = useState(null);

  // cache this with useCallback.  The second parameter (the dependency
  // array) is an empty array because there are no items that, should they
  // change, we should create a new copy.  That is to say we should never
  // need to make a new copy because we have no dependencies that could
  // change.  This will now be the same instance of the same function each 
  // re-render.
  const handleMenuItem = useCallback((menuItem) => setMenuItem(menuItem), []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Menu items={data} handleMenuItem={handleMenuItem}></Menu>
      <div>{selectedItem}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Previously, handleMenuItem was set to a new copy of that function every time the App component was re-rendered, and `data` was also set to a new array (with the same entries) on each re-render.  This would cause the child component (Menu) to re-render each time App was re-rendered.  We don't want that.  We only want child components to re-render if ABSOLUTELY necessary.

Next is the Menu component.  There are pretty much no changes here, although I would urge you not to put spaces around your `=` within your JSX  (`key={index}` not `key = {index}`.

```js
import React from "react";
import MenuItem from "./menuItem";

const Menu = (props) => {

    return (
        <>
            {props.items.map((item, index) => {
                return <MenuItem key={index} handleMenuItem={props.handleMenuItem} value={item}/>
            })
            }
            {console.log("menuItem")}
        </>
    )
};

export default React.memo(Menu);
```

For MenuItem, let's cache that click handler.

```js
import React from "react";

const MenuItem = (props) => {
  // cache this function
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => props.handleMenuItem(props.value), [props.value]);

    return (
        <>
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
            <p>{props.value}</p>
        </div>
        {console.log("render du MenuItem")}
        </>
    )

};

export default React.memo(MenuItem);
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your `handleMenuItem` function with [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to avoid rerendering when the function changes. This will create a single function reference that will be used in the `MenuItem` as props and will avoid rereading since it's the same function instance always.

I have used an empty dependency array in this case which is correct for your use case. If your function has any state references then they should be added to the array.

```
  const handleMenuItem = useCallback((menuItem) => {
    setMenuItem(menuItem);
  }, []);
```

[image: Edit relaxed-ride-1iigv4]

Comment: Thank you Amila, it worked perfectly, also it was possible that way to give a specific style to the selected `MenuItem` adding `color = {props.selectedItem === item ? "red" : "black"}` during the `map` function in `Menu` . The only components being re-rendered after are these whose style has to be changed. Thank you a lot